# How to use a Scala IDE (Eclipse or NetBeans based) to develop a Scala Lift web application with SBT?

Tags: eclipse, scala, netbeans, ide, sbt

I've switched to a plain text editor and console SBT from NetBeans because the last was enforcing Ant and used to have some other troubles with Scala. Now, as I have to explore others code (Lift examples for now) instead of just writing my own from scratch, I feel I miss debug, refactoring and definition/type lookup facilities of a good IDE.

So I am looking forward to go with some Scala IDE (Eclipse or NetBeans based) again, but I still want to use SBT as a build and dependency management tool (not Maven/Ant instead) and only use the IDE as an advanced code editor.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Is [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) out of the question? It has good Scala and SBT plugins.

Comment: I've tried it that day, @Philippe, but found it even overwhelmed with unnecessary entities and enforcing it's own style, maybe even more than Eclipse. And, as far as I've understood, it didn't really use SBT to build, it could only maintain semi-compatible project structure. What I want is an IDE entirely relying on SBT in everything SBT is meant for.

Comment: I use IntelliJ with sbt for all my Lift projects and it works just fine. I don't tell intelliJ to compile. And I start all my projects based on the templates you get from the lift site, so IntelliJ does not create the folder structure. I do recomment using the idea sbt plugin to generate the .idea folder with the correct configs.

Answer (score 1):

No personal experience, but looks like Scala-IDE keeps improving their SBT support.

http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/Changelog

Release 2.0.0-beta11 (released: 2011-10-03) makes a few mentions of using SBT.

Also, the docs at http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/SBT-based_build_manager show how to use SBT.